# how to get the name and value of the checked checkbox of child component from parent component in vue js?

Tags: vuejs3

**Child Component**

```
<template>
    <ul>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <div>
              <label class="form-control" ref="checkValue" v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
                <input type="checkbox" ref="checkUpdatedBox" :name="item.name" :value="item.name" @click="selectedFilteredArray(item)" />
                {{ item.name }}
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Here I want the name(item.name) or value(item.name) of the checkbox from the child component. As the input box is rendered dynamically with for loop.

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
      <ChildComponent ref="checkboxes"/>
</template>

<script>    
import SideBar from '../layouts/SideBar.vue'
export default {
         methods: {
            updateFunction() {
              const unCheckBoxes = this.$refs.checkboxes.$refs.checkUpdatedBox
              const unCheckBoxes1 = this.$refs.checkboxes.$refs.checkValue
              console.log('unCheckBoxes1   ', unCheckBoxes1.innerText)
              console.log(unCheckBoxes.checked) // true
            }
          }
    }
</script>
```

In parent component, I'm trying to access name and value of the checkbox with the help of **$refs** and yes I'm trying to get name and value of the checkbox from a function. I'm only getting to know that whether the checkbox is checked or not.

But i want to know that checked checkbox value(item.name) or name(item.name).

is there something I'm missing out?
or
Is there any other method to get the name or value?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use JavaScript to get value of selected checkbox.

```
var checkedValue = []; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValue.push({value:inputElements[i].value,name:inputElements[i].name});
      }
}
console.log(checkedValue);
```